# Digital Potentiometer AD5263 (AD5263BRUZ20) Query

Tags: digital-logic, potentiometer, dac, gain

I am planning to use DigiPot [AD5263BRUZ20](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5263.pdf)  ( Digital Potentiometer  IC Quad 8-Bit I2C) in my H/W setup for gain setting. Earlier it has 4 potentiometer in design (not digital pot), now I want to replace it with Digipot. Each digipot (out of 4) will be having different resistance value and need to be there all time.

I never used DigiPot earlier, so has some basic queries as below:

1) Does AD5263BRUZ20 has independent pot settings?

2) Since digital lines for all pots are same, will all 4 pot's will be active same time with different resistance value?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really need to learn how to read a datasheet, read the whole thing before using a part. Especially the absolute maximium ratings section.

> 1) Does AD5263BRUZ20 has independent pot settings?

Yes, that can be seen in the diagram, each of the RDACx registers sets a different pot.

> 2) Since digital lines for all pots are same, will all 4 pot's will be
>   active same time with different resistance value?

The pots will do whatever you command them to do. You can even set them into a sleep mode independently. Make sure you watch the Vdd and Vss range the inputs cannot be outside of this range. Also make sure that you don't exceed the current rating of 3mA continuous current for the inputs
[image: Yes]